# Workflow when using Appcelerator and IOS Deployment

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator to build smartphone apps, only iPhone right now but the plan is to expand into Android territory later.
I'm having some problems (as many others I understand) with understanding the provisioning profiles and ad-hoc deployment.
I have created a provisioning profile that contains the UDID's of my iPhone, my iPad and my sons iPhone. I build using Titanium Studio, and then select the "Install to IOS Device" to build an app and also an "ipa" file. Syncing with iTunes to my own devices.

I'm now planning to use TestFlight with the ipa file to distribute beta versions. It seems to work OK with the existing UDID's in the profile. The problem is now when I add more UDID's. Do I have to update the profile manually (on developer.apple.com), download it and fully rebuild my app for every added UDID? Or is there a simpler way? As I understand it, the profile is embedded into the "ipa" file, so does that mean I HAVE to rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do I have to update the profile manually (on developer.apple.com), download it and fully rebuild my app for every added UDID?"

Yep, it's exactly as you say. When you build your app, the provisioning profile the app is built against is embedded within the .ipa file. This is used to determine which devices can run the app, as TestFlight illustrates after the .ipa file is upload - all devices within that profile that match devices you've registered with TestFlight are listed. So after changing the device provisioning, you'll need to download and install the provisioning profile by dropping it into XCode, and then rebuild the app.

Comment: ok thanks, I was just hoping there would be a shortcut somewhere.